# Active Items in Nav on iPad not applying css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I select the item in the navigation it scrolls to the area I want, but keeps the hover background color and not the active background color I've assigned.

I'm using the Grayscale Bootstrap theme and it applies the active class to the list item so I have to target that like such:

```
<li class="page-scroll third fade-out active">
    <a href="#associates">
        Our <br style="display: none;">Associates
    </a>
</li>
```

With the following style: .active { background-color: #ff6802;}

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's a small piece of the code http://jsfiddle.net/xyms9/ Would it be better to provide a link to what I'm working on?

Comment: Yeah, a link to your site would be better.